# git push preserving history and branches

Tags: git, repository, push

I have a local repository I've created with 'git init' and started making commits.
A 'remote' repository has been created for my work on some server and now I need to 'update' it with my entire work (preserving history and branches).

I assume I need to first clone that 'remote' into my machine, then 'update' it somehow to hold the entire historical content and then push, but:
1. - How do I do that? 
2. - Is there a simple way to do that (meaning 'automatically' - so that git does it all for me)?

Cheers

Comment: Literally all you have to do is push. That'll put that certain branch on the remote, and you can do this for each branch (or use some flag to do it all at once).

Comment: Do I need to first "introduce" 'remote' to my 'local' repository somehow, and then do the 'push'?

Comment: What is your remote being hosted on? GitHub, GitLab, or some self-hosted (or corporate) machine? Please look at a basic git guide for how to add a remote and push.

Comment: It is a corporate machine. Now I realised there is already "something" in that 'remote' repository, meaning local repository shall be 'pushed' as a branch of 'remote', so that my 'master' branch becomes a 'someName' branch on 'remote', again - preserving all history.
How do I do that?

Comment: Genuine question — if it's corporate why don't you ask them? Regardless, much of this can be answered with a simple search.

Comment: 1. "they" say "figure it out, we don't know" (they have just created the remote repo in Bitbucket).
2. Searched for that but couldn't find a very specific (to-the-case) answer.

Comment: Look at how to push a branch to a remote of a different name. There are plenty of resources.

Answer (score 1):

> Now I realised there is already "something" in that 'remote' repository, meaning local repository shall be 'pushed' as a branch of 'remote', so that my 'master' branch becomes a 'someName' branch on 'remote', again - preserving all history.

That is the issue: you cannot just push, especially if the master branch has already some history.

If your commits add to the existing content, what you would do is replay them on top of the existing remote history:

```
cd /path/to/local/repo
git checkout master
git remote add origin /url/remote/repo
git fetch
git rebase origin/master
git push -u origin master
```

If the history is not related to the existing content, then it is easier to create an *empty* repo on the server side.
From there, a simple `git push --mirror` will push *everything* (all branches)

Answer (score 0):

> there is already "something" in that 'remote' repository, meaning
>   local repository shall be 'pushed' as a branch of 'remote', so that my
>   'master' branch becomes a 'someName' branch on 'remote', again -
>   preserving all history.

So the simplest way to solve your problem is to create a new branch with any name in your remote repo and push your local working copy's changes to that branch.

Simplest way to achieve is as follows:

Copy the url of the remote repo by using GitLab/GitHub
then make a new folder anywhere in your system, open gitbash and write the following command:

```
git init

git clone <Paste the url>
```

You will get all the files in the master in your folder.

Then create a branch:

```
git branch <branch_name>
```

This will create a a new branch locally
switch to the newly created branch as:

```
git checkout <branch_name>
```

Now paste all the files that you wanted to push to remote in the git folder.

Now we just have to commit as follows:

```
git add .
```

this command will add the files to the staging area.

```
git commit -m"Any message"
```

to commit the changes.

```
git push origin <branch_name>
```

Done!

**where origin is the remote name**
Since we didn't create a new remote and cloned the existing remote repo. So by default the remote name will be **origin**